# Cocoa persist coredata NSNumber from tableview not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, data-binding, tableview

I am unable to save numeric values to coredata via a bound tableview and arrayController. I have changed the code to return hardcoded values, it doesn't crash when i try edit the numeric column but doesn't persist the hardcoded value:

```
#import "StringToNumberTransformer.h"

@implementation StringToNumberTransformer

+ (Class)transformedValueClass { return [NSNumber class]; }

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { return YES; }

 - (id)transformedValue:(id)value {

   // return (value == nil) ? nil : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [value shortValue ]];
   //return (value == nil) ? nil : NSStringFromClass([value class]);
     return @"1";
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
//    return [value numberFromString:[value stringValue]];
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
}
    @end
```

Here is the link to the xib setup  ! http://tinypic.com/r/2nty41s/5 !
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs for Custom Value Transformers ([Value Transformer Programming Guide)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/CustomTransformer.html)

> A value transformer subclass must implement the transformedValueClass
>   class method. This method returns the class of the object that the
>   transformedValue: method returns.

Thus, your `transformedValueClass` returns the class for `NSNumber`, but your `transformedValue:` method returns an instance of type `NSString`

Since you're converting *from* an `NSString` *to* an `NSNumber`, I imagine you'll want to swap the implementations of your `transformedValue:` and `reverseTransformedValue:` methods.

Comment: Thanks, the core data value is an NSNumber so i think the transformedValue is correct to convert number to string right? I changed the transformedValueClass to NSString. When I run it in debug mode the transformValue method is definitely run when retrieving records so needs to convert from number to String. I don't understand why it isn't saving the values though.

Comment: Can you take screenshots or show code snippets for your use/configuration of the value transformer?

Comment: Sure, edited the post but can't get it to show, here is the url http://tinypic.com/r/2nty41s/5